# How do I run vino-server without a monitor attached in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vnc, headless

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 10.04 yesterday on a headless home server. I use the server for a variety of purposes, and what I don't know how to do via SSH I've alway been able to do through VNC. However, since the upgrade vino-server will no longer run if there isn't a monitor attached. Before it used to start up without a problem. Even by attempting to run the server via SSH gives me a "could not load display" error.

Summary: I need to get vino-server running at boot time on a server with Ubuntu 10.04, *without* a monitor attached.

Answer (score 4):

vino-server provides remote access to a console Gnome session, and it doesn't start until the Gnome session starts (meaning *after* you log into the GUI login window).  There's [some indication on the Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8000496&postcount=2) that you can fool it into running without a monitor by

1. configuring GDM to autologin instead of showing the login screen; and
2. configuring an *xorg.conf* to use the "vesa" driver.

But that post also indicates the Xserver was limited to 640x480 resolution.  This may be configurable by changing the kernel's console framebuffer resolution; and it may be that Ubuntu 10.04 already changes that default enough to work at a higher resolution.

---

**Updated**
As others have mentioned already, you probably [need to use Xvnc](https://superuser.com/questions/71725/xserver-that-i-can-reconnect-to/71727#71727) (RealVNC or TightVNC).  I don't know how easy it will be to configure GDM to launch an Xvnc server.

Instead, most tutorials recommend launching Xvnc from *xinetd*, and enabling XDMCP so that Xvnc can communicate with GDM.  I've just found [this Ubuntu forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9244160&postcount=605) that details enabling Xvnc + GDM in Lucid; it is very clear and not difficult to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Ignacio is right: You should use Xvnc. That way Xvnc will start instead of a "real" X11 Display with the difference, that you can connect to it via VNC.

I found [this howto](http://oapeon.blogspot.com/2010/05/ubuntu-1004-vnc-based-login-server.html). But i haven't tried it on my machine but i tried a similar setup on my 9.04 box a year ago. 
My solution was to tell gdm to launch X11vnc instead of registering it with xinetd service. X11vnc (not Xvnc) attaches (or spawns?) to a real X11 session. But the idea is quite the same.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I ran into this issue and hope this can help. I'm currently running **Ubuntu 18.04** so hopefully this applies, and running **Vino VNC Server**. I had the same problem of needing to VNC into a headless server.

First, install the dummy driver:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-dummy
```

Then after the driver gets installed, create a new `xorg.conf` in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with the following (you can backup your other one if it exists already to revert if needed):

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier    "Configured Video Device"
    Driver        "dummy"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier    "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync     31.5-48.5
    VertRefresh   50-70
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier    "Default Screen"
    Monitor       "Configured Monitor"
    Device        "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth  24
    SubSection    "Display"
      Depth       24
      Modes       "1600x900"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Then reboot the system and it should work! Worked for me, but I had put it in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf` which proved **incorrect**

Comment: This did not work me on a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, post startup, post startup I couldnot startup VNC

Answer (score 1):

If it's headless then don't bother with vino at all. Just stick to Xvnc, since you don't need an actual "physical" X server running on the system.